# Sequence and limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find a sequence $b_n$ that contradicts the following:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ goes to zero, $b_n$ equals sum of $a_k$ where $k$ goes from $1$ to $n$,
Then $b_n$ converges!

So is there such a $b_n$ sequence but doesn't converge even to infinity?

Answer (score 4):

Take $a_n=1/n$ and
$$
b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.
$$
Then $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, but $b_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ (see the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))).

Comment: Read the question again, I ment doesnt converge even to infinity

Comment: @TommyKad I answered your original question which was as follows: "So is there such a bn sequence but doesnt converge?".

Comment: Yes, in our course infinity is considered convergent, so doesnt converge is something like (-1)^n

Comment: This is usually not the case. See, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Infinite_limits): "If a sequence tends to infinity, or to minus infinity, then it is divergent (however, a divergent sequence need not tend to plus or minus infinity)". Consider asking another question and explaining in detail exactly what you need.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb You can occasionally switch the sign of $1/k$ term, so that your $(b_n)$ sequence bounces between some bounds (and the bounds don't have to be constant). This way you'll get a bounded, divergent series with differences convergent to zero.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks for your comment. That is true, we can get a bounded divergent series by switching the signs of $1/k$ appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Take $$b_n = \sin\sqrt n$$
- it oscillates 'forever' but oscillation slow down and down with $n$ growing, so $a_n = b_{n+1}-b_n$ tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

**Edit:** the above is wrong, indices are shifted by one. Should be $a_1=b_1$ and $a_n = b_n-b_{n-1}$ for $n>1.$

Comment: Please read the question again,

Comment: You need an to go to zero and bn to be equal sum of an from 1 to k and that bn doesnt converge even to infinity

Comment: Nice example (+1)!

Comment: @TommyKad Precisely. That's what you asked for: $a_n$ tends to zero and $b_n$, being a partial sum of $(a_n)$, does not converge. Not even to infinity.

Comment: If you take an=bn+1 - bn , then an=sinsqrt(n+1)-sinsqrt(n), bn has to be the sum of an from 1 to n, therefor it wont equal sinsqrt(n)!!

Comment: Right, I messed up indices, should be one less. Fixing in the answer. Anyway that was a minor mistake, the main idea remains valid and should be clear (I hope).